# Is the phrase "Me siento mal" grammatically correct in Spanish?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, gramática, adjetivos, adverbios

Primero mi pregunta en español:

**¿Es la oración «Me siento mal» gramaticalmente correcta en español?**

**Details in English**

It is my understanding that, in English, the sentences:

> I feel sick

and

> I feel bad

can be translated as

> Me siento mal

In English (and I would imagine this is true of the Spanish as well), the sentence is a copular construction and one in which the verb "feel" (sentir) is followed by an adjective.  If this is the case, wouldn't

> Me siento malo *(if you are a male)*

be the grammatically correct way of saying this?

I had thought "malo" was only shortened to "mal" when it precedes a singular masculine noun.  And yet, if you look at the Ngram below, "Me siento mal" is overwhelmingly the more common way of saying this.

[image]

Is this one of those things where common practice is more prevalent than grammatically correct usage?  For example, in English, on the telephone, many might say, "It's me" instead of "It is I."  The fact that Google's Ngram specifically searches books makes me question this, but books could also include dialogue that might intentionally mirror common usage.

Enough conjecture from me.  If any of you have any thoughts or opinions (or answers!), please share them with us.

**Detalles en español**

Tengo entendido que, en inglés, las oraciones:

> I feel sick

y

> I feel bad

se pueden traducir como

> Me siento mal

En inglés (e imaginaría que esto es verdad en español también), la oración es una construcción copulativa y una en que el verbo «sentir» (*feel*) es seguido por un adjetivo.  Si esto es el caso, ¿no sería

> Me siento malo *(si eres hombre)*

la manera gramaticalmente correcta de decir esto?

Había pensado que «malo» era sólo acortada cuando la precede un sustantivo masculino singular.  Y sin embargo, si nos fijamos en el Ngram a continuación, «Me siento mal» es abrumadoramente la manera más común de decir esto.

[Véase la imagen de arriba.]

¿Es esto una de estas cosas donde la práctica común es más prevalente que el uso gramaticalmente correcto?  Por ejemplo, en inglés, al teléfono, muchos podrían decir, *“It’s me”* en lugar de *“It is I.”* El hecho de que Google Ngram busque libros me hace cuestionar esto, pero libros podría incluir también diálogo que podría reflejar intencionalmente el uso común.

Eso es suficiente conjetura por mi parte.  Si alguno de ustedes tiene pensamientos u opiniones (¡o respuestas!), por favor, ¡compártanlos con nosotros!

Comment: @walen  For the first time ever, I actually went through the revisions line by line.  Most of the time, my reaction was, _Yep, I forgot about that little rule_ or _Yep, I got that one wrong_ or _That must just be how they say it in Spanish._  However, there were a few that I thought were acceptable and I am now left wondering if the edit was made due to regional preferences or personal stylistic preferences.  Either way is fine.  I'm just trying to learn even more from you.  I'll lay out the ones I thought could go either way in my next comment to you.

Comment: @walen The ones I felt were OK follow: "cuando precede" (vs. cuando _la_ precede), "_en el_ teléfono" (vs. _al_ teléfono), and "_de_ mi parte" (vs. _por_ mi parte).  If my assumptions are incorrect, or perhaps just not said that way in your region, please explain why or tell me which Spanish-speaking region you live in or have spent the most time in.  Gracias de antemano.  (Also, any citations you can provide would also be helpful for future reference and conveying any lessons learned to others.)

Comment: Please, could you use in your question the difference between "estar mal" and "estar enfermo"? When looking for the question, it would be cool to find this one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sí, es gramaticalmente correcta.

Efectivamente, el DPD y la *Nueva gramática española* dicen que *malo* (adjetivo) solo se apocopa en *mal* cuando precede a un sustantivo. Y aquí no va precediendo a nada, sino a final de frase. ¿Dónde está el problema?

Pues que en las oraciones

> Me siento mal

y otras similares como

> Esto está mal

la palabra *mal* no es un adjetivo (ni un sustantivo), sino un **adverbio**. Y hay pues que buscar en el diccionario las acepciones de *mal* como tal:

> **[mal<sup>2</sup>](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NyEeGCh)**
>
> Del lat. *male*.
>
> 1. adv. Contrariamente a lo que es debido, sin razón, imperfecta o desacertadamente, de mala manera. *Pedro se conduce siempre mal. Antonio lo hace todo mal.*
> 2. adv. Contrariamente a lo que se apetece o requiere, infelizmente, de manera impropia o inadecuada para un fin. *La estratagema salió mal. El enfermo va mal.*
> 3. adv. difícilmente. *Mal puedo yo saberlo. Mal se podrá resolver en tan breve término tan arduo negocio.*
> 4. adv. Poco, escasamente. *Te has enterado mal. Cenó mal.*

Luego en frases como

> Me siento mal
>   Me encuentro mal

*mal* se usa como adverbio y significa "contrariamente a lo que es debido o a lo que se apetece". Como lo debido es encontrarse bien (sano), encontrarse mal significaría "sentirse enfermo", y por eso el significado de "mal" en estas frases se puede confundir con el significado de "malo" (adjetivo) como "enfermo".

Date cuenta, para finalizar, que las frases contrarias

> Me siento bien
>   Me encuentro bien

usan *[bien](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5TkGdE0)* (adverbio, con el significado de "según es debido", "según se apetece" aunque también con el de "con buena salud, sano") y no *bueno* (adjetivo). Curioso que *bien* como adverbio incluya el sentido de "con buena salud" y *mal* como adverbio no incluya el sentido de "con mala salud, enfermo".

He preguntado directamente a la RAE, dado que los adverbios *bien* y *mal* parecen tener una serie de paralelismos en sus acepciones:

```
Bien                           --> Mal
---------------------------------------------------------------------
según es debido                --> contrariamente a lo que es debido
según se apetece               --> contrariamente a lo que se apetece
sin inconveniente o dificultad --> difícilmente
muy                            --> poco, escasamente
```

Sin embargo, la acepción de *bien* como "con buena salud, sano" no tiene su contrapartida en el adverbio *malo*. Me responden lo siguiente:

> En relación con su consulta, nos complace remitirle la siguiente
>   información:
>
> Efectivamente, el adverbio *mal*, paralelamente a una de las acepciones
>   de *bien* (‘con buena salud’) puede significar ‘con mala salud’. El
>   *Diccionario del estudiante* (2011), de la RAE, sí registra esta
>   acepción:
>
> **mal<sup>2</sup>**. adv. … 3. Con mala salud. *No ha venido a trabajar
>   porque se encuentra mal.* […]
>
> Agradecemos sus observaciones, que
>   remitimos al Instituto de Lexicografía, para que revise este artículo
>   del diccionario.

Así pues, aunque en el DLE no aparezca, sí que es cierto que la RAE ha contemplado este significado del adverbio *mal* en otros diccionarios. Y es posible que en la próxima revisión del DLE aparezca ya esta acepción.

---

Actualización 2019: esta respuesta ha quedado desactualizada porque la RAE ha incluido en su edición 23.2 la acepción de *mal* que faltaba, tal y como dijeron que harían. Por tanto, si se pulsa el enlace al DLE en la definición de *mal* arriba ya se puede leer:

> 5. adv. Con mala salud, enfermo. *Me encuentro mal y no voy a poder viajar.*

Esta quinta acepción sería la que aplica realmente en ejemplos como "me siento mal" y similares.

Comment: También crea confusión que malo signifique enfermo, puedes decir «estoy malo». Aunque *me siento mal* puede ser enfermo o simplemente un poco mareado, por ejemplo.

Comment: Presumably the opposite is _me siento bien_ which perhaps, if I am correct, you might add to your answer?

Comment: @mdewey ¡hecho!

Comment: Su respuesta me dejó alucinada con su calidad y exhaustividad.  Me tomará un poco de tiempo para digerirla, pero tendré ganas de revisarla con un ojo atento más tarde.  Mientras tanto, entre su respuesta y la de Ender Look (gracias también!), tengo una mayor comprensión del sentido de estos tipos de frases.  Muchas gracias.

Comment: @LisaBeck ha pasado el tiempo y la RAE ha añadido la acepción que faltaba para el adverbio "mal", he actualizado la respuesta para indicarlo. Por tanto, es correcto usar "mal" en "me siento mal", actúa como adverbio y significa "con mala salud".

Comment: @nadie Repuesta de "Ender look": NO digas "Me siento malo":
Estas diciendo "I feel evil."

Answer (score 3):

Voy a darte mi opinión como persona que habla español de nacimiento.  Me refiero a que yo no "analizo" mucho las frases, sino que las digo como me parece más natural.

> I feel sick. / I feel bad.

Yo lo diría como:

> Me siento mal. / Me encuentro mal. (More European)

O, si sabes que estas realmente enfermo:

> Estoy enfermo. (I'm sick.)

"Me siento mal" no significa que necesariamente estés enfermo, puedes estar mareado, indispuesto, etc.

NO digas "Me siento malo":

1. Suena raro.
2. Estas diciendo "I feel evil.". En este sentido "malo" es de "maldad" (evilness).
   Recuerda que lo mismo ocurre con "I feel good/fine", es "Me siento/encuentro bien" no "bueno" ya que significaría "I feel that I am a good person.". "Bien" aquí es normal o saludable.

También si te encontrabas mal y ahora no, puedes decir "Me siento/encuentro mejor (better than before)."  o "Ahora me siento/encuentro mejor [que antes (opcional)]"